# how to exit a foreach loop by pressing Esc key in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have some strings in a list which i want to iterate until I press the Esc button.

```
set list {{black board} {chalk} {duster}}
foreach list1 $list {
```

I want to iterate the list one by one by pressing button "K". Once I press Esc it should exit from the `foreach` loop.

Is it possible to write this in TCL?

Comment: Yes. Please read http://wiki.tcl.tk/14693

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example incorporating Glenn's suggestion and runs on UNIX:

```
proc enableRaw {{channel stdin}} {
  exec /bin/stty raw -echo <@$channel
}
proc disableRaw {{channel stdin}} {
  exec /bin/stty -raw echo <@$channel
}

set l [list a b c d]
enableRaw
foreach el $l {
  puts "$el"
  set c 0
  while {$c != 107 && $c != 27} {
    set c [scan [read stdin 1] %c]
  }
  if {$c == 27} { break }
}
disableRaw
```

If there is an error in the program, however, or the user presses CTRL-C, they will be stuck in raw mode; therefore you may want to add an exit handler to your program that calls disableRaw.